# Collection Reference is broken

Tags: velo

This is about Wix collection references.

I have 2 collections set up. Collection 1 is a list of people with addresses and includes a state abbreviation field. Collection 2 is a list of states, with other state info, and 1 of the fields is the state abbreviation, which is the Main Field.

On collection 1, when I change the state abbreviation field from Text to Reference, and set the correct referenced collection, then all the field's values change to "Reference is broken". I can edit each item and set the value to it's correct value.

Am I doing something wrong or is that how Wix references work? Do you have to set EACH reference item's value?

Comment: Reassigning to wixcode. Assume this is about the Wix web-site tool?

Comment: Yes, this is about the Wix general website design, not Wix code though.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will have to change each item's reference value. In general, it is recommended that you start with the proper field type so you don't run into issues like this.

You need to change each item because the reference field does not actually hold the value from the Main Field of the referenced collection (e.g. NY). Really, it holds the ID value from the referenced collection (e.g. 363293a4-4b8f-45c1-9559-6cfc2b37c9f9).

You can verify that this is indeed the case by setting the reference values and then switching the field back to Text. You will see the IDs. You can then switch back to Reference and it will work properly because the ID is what the reference really uses.

One benefit of this approach is that you can easily change the Main field in the referenced collection without breaking the references.